# Please help figure out what's wrong with this database update statement from text boxes in C#

Tags: c#, sql

```
comm.CommandText =
        "UPDATE studbiodata([Registration Number], Surname, Othernames, Email,"
      + " Phone, Address, Sex, [Birth Date], Religion, [Marital Status],"
      + " [No. of Children], [Next of Kin], Relationship, [Next of Kin Address])"
      + "SET ([Registration Number] ='" + txtRegNo.Text
      + "', Surname = '" + txtSurname.Text
      + "', Othernames = '" + txtOthernames.Text
      + "', Email = '" + txtEmail.Text
      + "', Phone = '" + txtPhone.Text
      + "', Address = '" + txtMainAdd.Text
      + "', Sex = '" + txtSex.Text
      + "', [Birth Date]= '" + txtBirthDate.Text
      + "', Religion = '" + txtReligion.Text
      + "', [Marital Status]= '" + txtMarital.Text
      + "', [No.of Children] = '" + txtChildren.Text
      + "', [Next of Kin]= '" + txtKin.Text
      + "', Relationship ='" + txtRelationship.Text
      + "', [Next of Kin Address]= '" + txtKinAdd.Text
      + "' WHERE [Registration Number]= '" + txtRegNo.Text + "')";
```

The error message I get after trying to update from a web-form is:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '('. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 at Transcript.studentprofileedit.btnUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 in C:\Users\Administrator.femzy-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Transcript Reloaded\Transcript\studentprofileedit.aspx.cs:line 119
```

Comment: Step 1: Get the sql out of the web-form.

Comment: You should never create sql like `UPDATE TABLE SET Column = ' + USER_INPUT + '''`

Comment: Why does everyone assume that code needs to be secure? What if this is for a demo about the dangers of SQL injections?

Comment: @trutheality, we cannot and *should* not assume what the asker or (more importantly) the viewer that comes in from google will do with the code presented *except* to assume *they might actually use it*. If there's a vulnerability, **shine the brightest spotlight on it and fix it.**

Comment: The message says that after two days nobody ( neigther you ) will be able to mantain that code anymore...

Comment: Just curious as to why there are donwnvotes on the question.  This is a good question for a beginner to ask.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing I see wrong is that it's a classic example of how to make your site vulnerable to SQL injection.  This is exactly how ***NOT*** to code a sql statement using user input.

Probably what's happening is that the user is entering something with a single quote (apostrophe) and it's messing with the statement.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Avoiding_SQL_Injection

**Use [parameterized queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml) or stored procedures with parameters as your absolute first step.**  That will eliminate erros caused by unexpected user input  ("O'Connor" as a last name, for example, would cause an error in a statement coded this way).  **Then** if there are still problems, go back and look at the statement.  You can use user input (almost every program does) - you just have to do it safely.

(last edit - one more good article)

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: Actually, the reason why its requiring user input is this: the information are all already stored in database by supposed students, so i read all the table entries back to textboxes to allow the student access to correct errors and there after they can update the database with the corrected version.

Comment: @Femzy, the original source might be you, but once a user has had a chance to modify it, *it is no longer safe.* Be as defensive as possible when dealing with user input and data.

Comment: Please be better than I was when I was a new developer and learn to code securely/defensively RIGHT AWAY!  Use the OWASP website as a great starting point.  It's absolutely critical to learn it now and get in good habits when you're starting out rather than trying to re-learn how to do things later!

Comment: You make a valid point. But seem to have deliberately not pointed out the error. Very negative approach to helping someone. -1

Comment: @Michael Meyers and @stupid-phil - Sorry, I didn't deliberately not point out the error.  I mistakenly assumed that the issue was unexpected user input, which is why I stressed the line about using parameterized queries as a first step.  @Mike Miller's answer is, I believe, a better answer than mine now that I see it, which is why I voted him up.  He truly saw what I missed, but I left this answer out there because the "O'Connor" issue would still exist the way it's coded.  I do believe that I earned the downvotes for missing the right answer, however.  Cheers!

Comment: @David Stratton - Fair play, not many would hold their hands up ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is wrong, you don't need to specify the column list first.

UPDATE studbiodatarital SET [Registration Number] ='" + txtRegNo.Text + "', Surname = '" + txtSurname.Text + "', Othernames = '" + txtOthernames.Text + "', Email = '" + txtEmail.Text + "', Phone = '" + txtPhone.Text + "', Address = '" + txtMainAdd.Text + "', Sex = '" + txtSex.Text + "', [Birth Date]= '" + txtBirthDate.Text + "', Religion = '" + txtReligion.Text + "', [Marital Status]= '" + txtMarital.Text + "', [No.of Children] = '" + txtChildren.Text + "', [Next of Kin]= '" + txtKin.Text + "', Relationship ='" + txtRelationship.Text + "', [Next of Kin Address]= '" + txtKinAdd.Text + "' WHERE [Registration Number]= '" + txtRegNo.Text + "')

Comment: You may or may not technically fix his present issue, but the vulnerability remains. **Do not go directly to the database with unsanitized user inputs.**

Comment: BTW. by answering I'm not condoning the approach and agree whole heartily with the above.  Gone through the OWASP guides, survived Pen. Tests and the PCI process and loved every minute.

Comment: Tx guys like mike said, i did n't need to specify the column list first, i removed the column list and it worked, i will research more into Parameterized Query as suggested for more secure designs.

Comment: Take a look at Entity Framework too and take away the drudgery of working with SQL.